# Python String Comparison--Problems With Special/Unicode Characters

Tags: python, string

I'm writing a Python script to process some music data. It's supposed to merge two separate databases by comparing their entries and matching them up. It's almost working, but fails when comparing strings containing special characters (i.e. accented letters). I'm pretty sure it's a ASCII vs. Unicode encoding issue, as I get the error:

"Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal"

I realize I could use regular expressions to remove the offending characters, but I'm processing a lot of data and relying too much on regexes makes my program grindingly slow. Is there a way to have Python properly compare these strings? What is going on here--is there a way to tell whether it's storing my strings as ASCII or Unicode?

EDIT 1: I'm using Python v2.6.6. After checking the types, I've discovered that one database spits out me Unicode strings and one gives ASCII. So that's probably the problems. I'm trying to convert the ASCII strings from the second database to Unicode with a line like

```
line = unicode(f.readline().decode(latin_1).encode(utf_8))
```

but this gives an error like:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm not sure why the 'ascii' codec is complaining since I'm trying to decode *from* ASCII. Can anyone help?

Comment: "use regular expressions to remove the offending characters": not possible until you know what the offending characters are and why they are offending, and deleting inconvenient data is not usually a good idea. The solution is more likely to be decoding your `str` objects with the correct encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unicode vs Bytes**

First, some terminology. There are two types of strings, encoded and decoded:

- Encoded. This is what's stored on disk. To Python, it's a bunch of 0's and 1's that you might treat like ASCII, but it could be anything -- binary data, a JPEG image, whatever. In Python 2.x, this is called a "string" variable. In Python 3.x, it's more accurately called a "bytes" variable.
- Decoded. This is a string of actual characters. They could be encoded to 8-bit ASCII strings, or it could be encoded to 32-bit Chinese characters. But until it's time to convert to an *encoded* variable, it's just a Unicode string of characters.

**What this means to you**

So here's the thing. You said you were getting one ASCII variable and one Unicode variable. That's actually not true.

- You have one variable that's a string of bytes -- ones and zeros, presumably in sets of 8. This is the variable you assumed, incorrectly, to be ASCII.
- You have another variable that's Unicode data -- numbers, letters, and symbols.

Before you compare the string of bytes to a Unicode string of characters, you have to make some assumptions. In your case, Python (and you) assumed that the string of bytes was ASCII encoded. That worked fine until you came across a character that *wasn't* ASCII -- a character with an accent mark.

So you need to find out what that string of bytes is encoded as. It might be latin1. If it is, you want to do this:

```
if unicode_variable == string_variable.decode('latin1')
```

Latin1 is basically ASCII plus some extended characters like Ç and Â.

*If* your data is in Latin1, that's all you need to do. But if your string of bytes is encoded in something else, you'll need to figure out what encoding that is and pass it to decode().

The bottom line is, there's no easy answer, unless you know (or make some assumptions) about the *encoding* of your input data.

**What I would do**

Try running var.decode('latin1') on your string of bytes. That will give you a Unicode variable. If that works, and the data looks correct (ie, characters with accent marks look like they belong), roll with it.

Oh, and if latin1 doesn't parse or doesn't look right, try utf8 -- another common encoding.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was reading in data from a text file that I could verify was encoded in utf-8, so I just decoded it with utf_8 and my special character problems went away. I didn't know reading test files was so complicated...

Answer (score 0):

You might need to preprocess the databases and convert everything into UTF-8. My guess is that you've got Latin-1 accented characters in some entries.

---

As to your question, the only way to know for sure is to look. Have your script spit out those that don't compare, and look up the character codes. Or just try `string.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')` and see what happens.

Comment: How should the OP "spit out" the strings? What character codes? Look up in what? What makes you assume that the OP has text encoded in latin1, or that the default encoding on his system is latin1? What is the point of .encode('utf8')??? [If the decode succeeds, you get unicode which is guaranteed NOT to fail encoding as UTF-8]

Comment: that's a lot of questions. by "spit out" I mean surround the test with try/except, and print to stderr whatever causes an error. if I see something like '\xc3\xbcmlaut\n', I'd have something useful for diagnosis. your point about the encode('utf8') is good, I didn't think that through enough.

Comment: If you re-encode it to UTF8, you go back to comparing a Unicode variable to a string of bytes. The right thing to do is to compare two decoded unicode variables.

Comment: not if you do the same to both strings. but you're right, re-encoding was not the right thing to do. as I said, "I didn't think that through enough". I was going by something I recently did converting my iPod Touch music db using Python, and having encoding issues with the latin1 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Converting both to unicode should help:

```
if unicode(str1) == unicode(str2):
    print "same"
```

Comment: Ummm ... looks like an implicit conversion to unicode is failing; making it explict conversion is going to help?

Answer (score 0):

To find out whether YOU (not it) are storing your strings as `str` objects or `unicode` objects, `print type(your_string)`.

You can use `print repr(your_string)` to show yourself (and us) unambiguously what is in your string.

By the way, exactly what version of Python are you using, on what OS? If Python 3.x, use `ascii()` instead of `repr()`.